# Using GDB on qtcreator-not supporting python scripting

Tags: c++, gdb, qt5, qt-creator

I try to debug a trivial `helloworld` cpp project with qtcreator.

When I start debugging the project, I obtain an error saying:

```
The selected build of GDB does not support Python scripting.
It cannot be used in Qt Creator.
```

My system is `debian9`

My QT version  is `5.14.2`
Here is my .pro file:

```yaml
QT += widgets
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES  = main.cpp
```

Can anyone show me how I should configure GDB with QT to avoid this error?

Comment: FYI: [Automate Debugging with GDB Python API](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/automate-debugging-with-gdb-python-api), [Qt Forum: Debugger does not start. GDB not support Python scripting.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/41667/debugger-does-not-start-gdb-not-support-python-scripting)

Comment: You might have gdb-minimal installed (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507007/49439 ). Can you show the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep gdb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mark Plotnik (Thank you Mark) suggested, you have a `gdb-minimal` installed.

Running `dpkg --get-selections | grep gdb`, you should have an ouput like the following:

```sh
gdb-minimal                 install
gdbm-l10n                   install
libgdbm-compat4:amd64       install
libgdbm6:amd64              install
wireless-regdb              install
```

Only `gdb-minimal`, there is no `gdb`.

Here is what I did to solve this problem on my `debian 9` system:

```sh
sudo apt install gdb
```

to get the full `gdb`.

If you rerun the command after the installation `dpkg --get-selections | grep gdb`, you should have :

```sh
gdb                         install
gdb-minimal                 deinstall
gdbm-l10n                   install
libgdbm-compat4:amd64       install
libgdbm6:amd64              install
wireless-regdb              install
```

You should have `gdb` installed and `gdb-minimal` uninstalled.

After this, I retested debugging on `qtCreator` and it works now.

Comment: On Debian 11 BullsEye installing gdb will automatically uninstall gdb-minimal. Uninstalling manually before installing gdb will uninstall a few other packages like kde-plasma-desktop and such, which usually you don't want. If you simply install gdb, apt takes care of the dependency.